# How to use zipsplit (or equivalent) on very large files?

Tags: bash, compression

According to the man pages, zipsplit does not work on files larger than 2GB.

Is there an equivalent or alternative that would allow me to break up, say, 4GB of files into 500MB chunks in a way that a typical Windows user could access easily? ( I say "typical Windows user" to exclude solutions like gzip, tar, and split(1) ... these aren't workable for the purpose at hand)

Thanks!

Comment: typo in title :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/) is a free archiving tool that will do what you're asking for.

Ehtyar.

Comment: Thanks! The linux version -- p7zip -- seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the RAR format?  [WinRAR](http://www.rarlabs.com) can do what you are asking quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

For a very minimal solution, you can just split your file and distribute the parts with a .bat file something like this:

```
@echo Please wait..
copy bigarchive.part1+bigarchive.part2+bigarchive.part3 bigarchive.zip
```

Of course, 7zip/winrar/etc will provide a nice interface, crc checking and whatnot.

So I don't exactly recommend this method, but I thought I'd post it for completeness.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but a good tip nonetheless. Thanks!